# Looking for a short-story set in a post-apocalyptic environment

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short-story set in a post-apocalyptic environment – volcanic eruption I think. The main character is a young woman who has a rather nasty character for a boyfriend. He’s abusive and uses violence to get what he wants and for the hell of it. I seem to remember oldsters living in the same space that’s maybe an underground parking garage. In a confrontation, the woman stands up to the boyfriend and he backs down when he realizes she is strong and angry enough to hurt him. She escapes to the ‘wild’ at the end of the story. Read in the 00s, part of an anthology.

Comment: was the eruption at Yellowstone, as in this question? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207888/post-apocalypse-short-story-about-a-young-woman-living-in-a-post-yellowstone-cal

Comment: Yes, Yellowstone! That sounds like the story I'm looking for. He-he, 'tolchoks'.

Comment: @Roysto I have just answered [the previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207888/post-apocalypse-short-story-about-a-young-woman-living-in-a-post-yellowstone-cal). Can you check if this is the story you are thinking of. If it is the same story please let us know so we can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: This is the story! Thank you so much.